# Got comment tag between span text to extract with xpath

Tags: dom, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm able to extract text from span below:

[image: chrome inspect]

with this xpath:

```
'./div/a/div/div/div/span/text()'
```

result:

```
(12)
```

but strangely, sometimes the server put comment tags in between so I'm unable to get the intended result,

```
review = product.xpath('./div/a/div/div/div/span/text()').extract_first()
In [1]: review
Out[2]: '('

review = product.xpath('./div/a/div/div/div/span').extract_first()

In [3]: review
Out[4]: '<span class="_2wY6y7fV">(<!-- -->12<!-- -->)</span>'
```

even though I don't see the comment tag on the chrome DevTools as in the first pic, very strange.

How you can bypass the comment tags (if rendered) and get the result?

Comment: Try `"".join(product.xpath('./div/a/div/div/div/span/text()').extract())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import re
reviews = "".join(product.xpath('./div/a/div/div/div/span').extract())
reviews = re.findall(r"\d+", reviews)
```

I mean do not use `/text()`, only get raw HTML and then retrieve integer value via Regex

Answer (score 3):

This is why it's best to avoid using text() to get the text nodes, instead using string() to get the string value of the containing element, which concatenates all the text nodes skipping the comments.

Unfortunately though some XPath-based applications only allow expressions that return nodes, they don't allow expressions that return strings, and if that's the case with Scrapy then you're hosed.